# Why does fe80:: work as a gateway?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipv6

Instead of fe80::1 I accidentally configured fe80:: as the default gateway on a Linux server. Surprisingly it worked and after a few tests, I noticed that it also works on all other machines I own. Even those that neither use fe80::1 as a gateway nor router advertisement and usually require a specific gateway address.

I can't find anything about this via google. I only find sites that tell you, that you can give routers fe80::1 as their IP so it can be reached via fe80::1. But nothing about fe80::(0).

Does anyone know more about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zero address in each subnet is reserved as the anycast router address. It's not often used or even implemented, but on the networks you tested on it apparently works.